# SQL - How to select a date by day before a specific datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

For example, lets say I have `5/2/2015` as my end point.  And I want to know the `max(Thursday)` before my end point.  How can I end at `4/30/2015`.  Also for this I do not have a column to select from.

So my whereclause needs to specify '5/2/2015'

sql 2012

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin 2012

Comment: I don't know if it's just me but this is as clear as mud to me. Can you show us what exactly you're after I.e. What data is going in and what results you want out?

Comment: @ChristianBarron There is no data going in and all I want to return is '4/30/2015'

Comment: select (however) from myTablr where datename = 'Thursday' and < '5/2/2015'

Comment: So you want to know the date of the Thursday between 2015-05-02 and 2015-04-30?

Comment: @ChristianBarron No, I want to know the closest Thursday before any given date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this While loop to achieve what you're after:

```
Declare @Date date = '2015-05-02'
While DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@Date) <> 'Thursday'
    begin
    Set @Date = DATEADD(dd, -1,@Date)
    end
Select @Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WEEKDAY function

```
SELECT TOP 1 column FROM table
WHERE WEEKDAY(column) = 5 AND column<'2015-05-02'
ORDER BY column DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run this as part of a SELECT, you can use the following:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 
      CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) >= 5 
        THEN 5 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())
        ELSE ((-2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()))) 
      END, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS PreviousThursday
```

With sample data:

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        theDate DATETIME
    )

INSERT  @Sample
SELECT  '20100805' UNION ALL    -- Thursday
SELECT  '20100806' UNION ALL    -- Friday
SELECT  '20100807' UNION ALL    -- Saturday
SELECT  '20100808' UNION ALL    -- Sunday
SELECT  '20100809' UNION ALL    -- Monday
SELECT  '20100810' UNION ALL    -- Tuesday
SELECT  '20100811' UNION ALL    -- Wednesday
SELECT  '20100812' UNION ALL    -- Thursday
SELECT  '20100813' UNION ALL    -- Friday
SELECT  '20100814'      

SELECT 
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, thedate), 
    thedate, 
    DATEADD(DAY, 
      CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, theDate) >= 5 
        THEN 5 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, theDate)
        ELSE ((-2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, theDate))) 
      END, theDate)
FROM @Sample
```

With a variable:

```
DECLARE @TheDate DATETIME = '5/2/2015'

SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, 
      CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @TheDate) >= 5 
        THEN 5 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @TheDate)
        ELSE ((-2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @TheDate))) 
      END, @TheDate) AS PreviousThursday
```